# $.connections can not read the hub of undefined (SignalR)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I will try to send data to the server whit SignalR 2. But I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'meldingenHub' of undefined

Here is the C# code on the server:

```
public class MeldingenHub : Hub
{
    public void Meld(string blogitem, string verdiendePunten)
    {
        Clients.All.BroadcastMessage(blogitem, verdiendePunten);
    }
}
```

Here I include all the file that is needed:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Here is the Client code that gives the error on the bold code.

```
var medlingenHub = $.connection.meldingenHub;

medlingenHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (blogitem, verdiendePunten) {
    $("#verdiendepunten").html(verdiendePunten);
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    var json = {
        ID: parseInt(this.dataset.id),
        Type: this.dataset.type,
        GebruikerID: "@(Model.DeBlog.Gebruiker.Id)",
        Punten: parseInt(this.dataset.punten),
        GestemdeGebruikerID: "@(Model.AangemeldeGebruiker)"
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "../api/Stem/Toevoegen?apiKey=@Model.ApiKey",
        type: "PUT",
        data: json,
        success: function (returnData) {

            if (returnData.Oke == false) {

                toonError(returnData)
            }
            else {

                plaatsKleuren(returnData);
                medlingenHub.server.meld(data.ID, data.Punten);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Note by the code above:** the code executes when I click on a button.

I've also added this line on the `Startup.Auth.cs` file:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.MapSignalR();
    // other code
}
```

I follow a tutorial on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried `[HubName("meldingenHub")]` for your hub?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Unless you want the hub name to differ from the class you shouldn't use the `HubName` attribute.  This has been known to cause issues for some, including messing up the `signalr/hubs.js` file.

Comment: Have you checked to see that there are no errors at the client side when opening the page?  Check for 404 errors in the client's network trace (F12 to open dev tools on Chrome, Firefox or IE).  Use the console in the dev tools to see if `$.connection` is defined and has the hub member defined as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it. I was working with a wrong scope of the `$.connection`. Here is my complete code I've made:

```
var punten = document.getElementsByClassName("punten-do-ajax");
var aantal = punten.length;

var conn = $.connection;

for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {

    punten[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

        @if (Model.DeBlog.StemmenToegelaten)
        {
            <text>
            votes(conn, this);
            </text>
        }
    });
}

function votes(conn, sender) {
    var medlingenHub = conn.meldingenHub;

    medlingenHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (blogitem, verdiendePunten) {
        $("#verdiendepunten").html(verdiendePunten);
    };

    conn.hub.start().done(function () {

        var json = {
            ID: parseInt(sender.dataset.id),
            Type: sender.dataset.type,
            GebruikerID: "@(Model.DeBlog.Gebruiker.Id)",
            Punten: parseInt(sender.dataset.punten),
            GestemdeGebruikerID: "@(Model.AangemeldeGebruiker)"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "../api/Stem/Toevoegen?apiKey=@Model.ApiKey",
            type: "PUT",
            data: json,
            success: function (returnData) {

                if (returnData.Oke == false) {

                    toonError(returnData)
                }
                else {

                    plaatsKleuren(returnData);
                    medlingenHub.server.meld(returnData.ID, returnData.Punten);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```